# How to set up many to many relationship in hibernate using XML mapping

Tags: xml, hibernate, many-to-many, pojo, xmlmapper

I have the following situation:

I am new to hibernate and I have a project to complete within the next days.

It is about a CRUD Web application in Java.The first steps have completed but I am really stuck and I cannot find any help in internet about the following situation:

i have an a Project Table which can have many Actions from Action table. ( many-to- many Relationship).

I also have a Payments table which has a primary key,( `paymentId`) and the 2 foreign keys of Project and action ( projectId,actionId) and also some other fields like `paymentMethod`, `price`, `startDate`, `endDate`. I actually use Payments table to connect each project to each action adding some additional information like amount, etc..

I hope i clarify my thoughts about the general view.

I don't know how i have to do the mapping files? Do i have to create 2 mapping files or 3?
(`Project.hbm.xml` , `action.hbm.xml` and `payments.hbm.xml`)

In the beginning i thought to do split the relationship into the following:

a project POJO class to have one to many relationship with payments ( and the mapping XML will the as having 1 relationship one to many) and the action POJO class to have many-to-one with payments ( also with the relevant XML mapping file).

And also have a POJO class with payments, including Objects Action and Projects, and the relevant one to many relationships in XML files.

I have not seen such an implementation to any tutorial neither to any site i don't know if that is ok ?

The only thing i found was Many-to-many relationship using annotation ( mainly) and having the mid-step table ( payments in my case ) with only the 2 foreign keys without any primary key and extra fields like these that i want.

project XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
     "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

      <hibernate-mapping>
      <class name="com.nisid.entities.Project" table="projects">
      <meta attribute="class-description"> This class contains the project records. </meta> 
       <id name="projectId" type="int" column="projectId"> 
        <generator class="native">

        </generator> 
    </id> 

    <many-to-one name="fkCustomer" class="com.nisid.entities.Customers"
            fetch="select">
            <column name="customerId" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
      <set name="payments"  
            lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
          <key>
                <column name="projectId" />
            </key>


            <one-to-many class="com.nisid.entities.Payment" />
        </set>
 <property name="projectName" column="projectName" type="string"/> 
    <property name="projectDescription" column="description" type="string"/> 
   </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Action xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

        <hibernate-mapping>
            <class name="com.nisid.entities.Action" table="actions" >
                <id name="actionId" type="int">
                    <column name="actionId" />
                    <generator class="native" >
                     </generator> 
                </id>
                <property name="actionName" type="string">
                    <column name="actionName"   />
                </property>

                <set name="payments" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
                    <key>
                        <column name="actionId" />
                    </key>
                    <one-to-many class="com.nisid.entities.Payment" />
                </set>

            </class>
        </hibernate-mapping>
```

Payment ( mapping xml):

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.nisid.entities.Payment" table="payments">


            <composite-id name="paymentId" class="com.nisid.entities.PaymentID" >

                <key-property name="myproject" column="projectId" />
                <key-property name="myaction" column="actionId" />

            </composite-id>

            <component name="myproject">

                <many-to-one name="project" class="com.nisid.entities.Project"
                    >
                    <column name="projectId" not-null="true" />
                </many-to-one>

            </component>

            <component name="myaction">

                <many-to-one name="action" class="com.nisid.entities.Action"
                    >
                    <column name="actionId" not-null="true" />
                </many-to-one>

            </component>


            <property name="amount" column="amount" type="int"/> 
            <property name="paymentDate" column="paymentDate" type="date"/> 
            <property name="paymentExpire" column="paymentExpire" type="date"/> 
            <property name="paymentMethod" column="paymentMethod" type="string"/>

        </class>
```

And ppojo classes:

Action:

```
/*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package com.nisid.entities;

    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.Set;

    /**
     *
     * @author p293
     */
    public class Action {

        private int actionId;
        private String actionName;
         private Set payments=new HashSet();



        public Action(){}

        public Action(String actionName) {
            this.actionName = actionName;
        }

        public int getActionId() {
            return actionId;
        }

        public void setActionId(int actionId) {
            this.actionId = actionId;
        }



        public String getActionName() {
            return actionName;
        }

        public void setActionName(String actionName) {
            this.actionName = actionName;
        }

        public Set getPayments() {
            return payments;
        }

        public void setPayments(Set payments) {
            this.payments = payments;
        }



        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 5;
            hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.actionName);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Action other = (Action) obj;
            if (!Objects.equals(this.actionName, other.actionName)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }





        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Action{" + "=" + actionName + '}';
        }



    }
```

Project:

```
/*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package com.nisid.entities;

    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.Set;

    /**
     *
     * @author p293
     */
    public class Project {

        private int projectId;
        private String projectName;
        private String projectDescription;
        private Customers fkCustomer;
        private Set payments=new HashSet();

        public Project(){


        }

        public Project( String projectName, String projectDescription) {

            this.projectName = projectName;
            this.projectDescription = projectDescription;
        }


        public int getProjectId() {
            return projectId;
        }

        public void setProjectId(int projectId) {
            this.projectId = projectId;
        }

        public String getProjectName() {
            return projectName;
        }

        public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
            this.projectName = projectName;
        }

        public String getProjectDescription() {
            return projectDescription;
        }

        public void setProjectDescription(String projectDescription) {
            this.projectDescription = projectDescription;
        }

        public Customers getFkCustomer() {
            return fkCustomer;
        }

        public void setFkCustomer(Customers fkCustomer) {
            this.fkCustomer = fkCustomer;
        }

        public Set getPayments() {
            return payments;
        }

        public void setPayments(Set payments) {
            this.payments = payments;
        }








        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.projectName);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Project other = (Project) obj;
            if (!Objects.equals(this.projectName, other.projectName)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


         @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Project{" + "projectName=" + projectName + ",with description="    +       projectDescription + '}';
        }



    }
```

Payment:

```
/*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package com.nisid.entities;

    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.Set;

    /**
     *
     * @author p293
     */
    public class Payment {

        private PaymentID paymentId=new PaymentID();
        private int amount;
        private Date paymentDate;
        private Date paymentExpire;
        private String paymentMethod;



        public Payment(int fkProjectId, int fkActionId, int amount, Date paymentDate, Date paymentExpire, String paymentMethod) {

            this.amount = amount;
            this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
            this.paymentExpire = paymentExpire;
            this.paymentMethod=paymentMethod;

        }

        public Payment(){}

        public PaymentID getPaymentId() {
            return paymentId;
        }

        public void setPaymentId(PaymentID paymentId) {
            this.paymentId = paymentId;
        }

        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public void setAmount(int amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public Date getPaymentDate() {
            return paymentDate;
        }

        public void setPaymentDate(Date paymentDate) {
            this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
        }

        public Date getPaymentExpire() {
            return paymentExpire;
        }

        public void setPaymentExpire(Date paymentExpire) {
            this.paymentExpire = paymentExpire;
        }

        public String getPaymentMethod() {
            return paymentMethod;
        }

        public void setPaymentMethod(String paymentMethod) {
            this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
        }

        public Project getProject(){
            return getPaymentId().getProject();
        }

        public Action getAction(){
            return getPaymentId().getAction();
        }

        public void setAction(Action action){
            getPaymentId().setAction(action);
        }

        public void setProject(Project project){
            getPaymentId().setProject(project);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 3;
            hash = 89 * hash + this.amount;
            hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.paymentMethod);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Payment other = (Payment) obj;
            if (this.amount != other.amount) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!Objects.equals(this.paymentMethod, other.paymentMethod)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }




        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Payment{" + "amount=" + amount + ", paymentMethod=" + paymentMethod + '}';
        }




    }
```

PaymentId:

```
/*
         * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */
        package com.nisid.entities;

        import java.util.Objects;

        /**
         *
         * @author lurtzaki
         */
        public class PaymentID {

            private Project myproject;
            private Action myaction ;

            public PaymentID(){
            super();}


            public Project getProject() {
                return myproject;
            }

            public void setProject(Project project) {
                this.myproject = project;
            }






    public Action getAction() {
                    return myaction;
                }
            public void setAction(Action action) {
                this.myaction = action;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                int hash = 3;
                hash = 17 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.myproject);
                hash = 17 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.myaction);
                return hash;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if (obj == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                    return false;
                }
                final PaymentID other = (PaymentID) obj;
                if (!Objects.equals(this.myproject, other.myproject)) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!Objects.equals(this.myaction, other.myaction)) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }



        }
```

New XML:

```
<composite-id name="paymentId"         class="com.nisid.entities.PaymentID">
        <key-many-to-one name="myproject" class="com.nisid.entities.Project">
            <column name="projectId"/>
         </key-many-to-one>
         <key-many-to-one name="myaction" class="com.nisid.entities.Action">
            <column name="actionId" />
         </key-many-to-one>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="amount" column="amount" type="int"/> 
    <property name="paymentDate" column="paymentDate" type="date"/> 
    <property name="paymentExpire" column="paymentExpire" type="date"/> 
    <property name="paymentMethod" column="paymentMethod" type="string"/>
```

Comment: A project table which can have many actions would not be many to many unless the actions could also have many projects. A clarification on this could help someone better answer the question.

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/

Comment: yes that is true. actions can also have many projects.. so the many to many is a bidirectional relationship is my case!

Answer (score 0):

if you need `paymentMethod`, `price`, `startDate`, `endDate` in your payment table then you need 3 entities mapping. you can map action and project many to many to each other using payment table as its `join table`. or if you have trouble searching for example of `many to many` with `join table`, you can also use many to one for each table action and project, to tabe payment.

edit:

try to test project and payment first, delete other potential error relation, if you success with it, you can implement it to other table. I thing the xml relation will be like this:

in the `project.hbm.xml` change the one-to-many became like this:

```
<list name="payments"
        inverse="true"
        cascade="save-update">
    <key column="projectId"/>
    <index column="actionId"/>
    <one-to-many class="Payment"/>
</list>
```

in the `action.hbm.xml` change the one-to-many became like this:

```
<list name="payments"
        inverse="true"
        cascade="save-update">
    <key column="actionId"/>
    <index column="projectId"/>
    <one-to-many class="Payment"/>
</list>
```

and in the `payments.hbm.xml` like this(i thing you dont need `<component>` tag there):

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.nisid.entities.Payment" table="payments">


        <composite-id name="paymentId" class="com.nisid.entities.PaymentID" >

            <key-property name="myproject" column="projectId" />
            <key-property name="myaction" column="actionId" />

        </composite-id>

        <many-to-one name="project" column="projectId" insert="false" update="false" not-null="true"/>
        <many-to-one name="action" column="actionId" insert="false" update="false" not-null="true"/>

        <property name="amount" column="amount" type="int"/> 
        <property name="paymentDate" column="paymentDate" type="date"/> 
        <property name="paymentExpire" column="paymentExpire" type="date"/> 
        <property name="paymentMethod" column="paymentMethod" type="string"/>

    </class>
```

Comment: hi i follow this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: but i cannot find out why this cannot play.. could you please send me any full example like the link above with an example using XML mapping???

Comment: wich way you want to read the value? also post your current xml here

Comment: hi i am going to post all the pojo classes and the XMLs that i have i hope that will help.

i want to read the values as the following:
say for example i have a project, each project is related to actions table and each project also has a price , payment method etc ( payment fields )

Comment: Hi,

For the payments table i have as primary key the composite key {projectId,actionId} so i am not sure if what you are telling above is right..

To test your suggestion i have to update my DB and make payments talbe with only 1 FK_key ( projectID) and paymentId as primary key. Beside that if Action table is missing i just have a one to many implementation from projects-> payments! which it is different from what i have to do

Comment: no you dont need to change that composite, you just need to change the one to many in the `project.hbm.xml` like my example, and you don't need to delete action table, just delete its relation for temporary, or if you want to test from all sides at once its up to you.

Comment: that's my example if you want to test from all sides at once. notice that i dont need to change your table structure, id structure or anything, i just change the one-to-many and many-to-one. got it?

Comment: as you suggested i added <index column="actionId"/> in my Project.hbm and i let Payment the same and i still get error:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 19; The content of element type "key" must match "(column)*".

Comment: just to clarify the payments xml should have only the
<composite-id name="paymentId" class="com.nisid.entities.PaymentID" ><key-property name="myproject" column="projectId" />
<key-property name="myaction" column="actionId" />

  </composite-id>

<many-to-one name="project" class="com.nisid.entities.Project"
  update="false" insert="false">
 <column name="projectId" not-null="true" />
 </many-to-one>  
                        
                    <many-to-one name="action" class="com.nisid.entities.Action" update="false" insert="false"> <column name="actionId" not-null="true" /> </many-to-one>

Comment: i add the full `payment.hbm.xml`, which one doesn't meet your requirenment?

Comment: Hi again,
First of all thanks for your time! i did the changes!

and i still get the following error:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 19; The content of element type "key" must match "(column)*".

Comment: just to mention i am using Hibernate 3.2.5

Comment: i review my code and i think now it is the correct one and the error message i get makes sense:

org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.nisid.entities.Project, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(projectId)]

Do you know why this happen???

Comment: i think that the problem is in the Payment.hbm where i say <key-property name="myproject" column="project" /> which means that i map a Project item to an int ( column project)..

Comment: if its a matter of object you can use `paymentId.projectId`, but i dont know if its about collumn, maybe your collumn in the database didn't same as your xml? as a advice you may consider to rename the table in the future so you didn't confuse about which is entity and which is real table or column like projectId and PROJECT_ID

Comment: yes, your projectId type in payment should be same as projectId in project, this also apply to actionId, so the problem is in your `class PaymentID.java`

Comment: in the paymentID java class i have declared two objects of type Project and Action, to i have to change them and put paymentId and actionId instead?

Comment: just change the type of that two objects to int. `private int myproject;` and `private int myaction;`

Comment: i finally solved the problem by changing payment.hbm to the entry above